# Is there is a way to create as much list as user input?

Tags: python, list, variables

I would like to know how to create as much list as user input.

Let's say user input is 4.

I want to create 4 list name Batch1 Batch2 Batch3 Batch4

to retrieve the data from the csv file with the same Batch1-4.csv name

```
for i in range(1,3):
    list("Batch{0}".format(i))
    print(Batch1)
```

I have tried this but resulting in error Batch1 is not defined because I didn't declare Batch1 directly.

Do you have any workaround?

Comment: could you share more information about your request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use list comprehension like so:

```
>>> main_list = ["batch{0}".format(i) for i in range(4)]
>>> main_list
['batch0', 'batch1', 'batch2', 'batch3']
```

If you want a list of lists do this:

```
>>> main_list = [["batch{0}".format(i)] for i in range(4)]
>>> main_list
[['batch0'], ['batch1'], ['batch2'], ['batch3']]
```

With user input your script might look like this:

```
n = int(input('Enter a number:'))
main_list = [["batch{0}".format(i)] for i in range(1,n+1)]
```

Comment: Doesn't he expect the name as a `list`?

Comment: main_list is a list. Not sure what you are asking.  I must admit the original question is a little confusing to me.

Comment: I think @RedCricket is on the right track. OP wants to write a program to generate `n` strings so that he can open files of the same name.

Comment: Thanks Red Cricket. You got my question right. Now the only thing i need to do is just specify main_list[i] for the batch[i] i want to use. Thanks again and sorry for my ambiguous question :)

Comment: If you constructed a list of lists, `main_list[0]` results in `['batch1']` and `main_list[0][0]` results in `'batch1'`.  It may be simpler to just construct a list so that `main_list[0]` results in `batch1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested loop concept. Create a `list` of `lists`. Like :

```
main_list = list()
for i in range(4):
    temp_list = ["batch{0}".format(i)]
    main_list.append(temp_list)
```

Comment: Thanks Taohidul, However I adjust your code a little bit for my code purposes my temp_list = "batch{0}".format(i) but the rest work just fine. Thanks again